# How to make a class diagram in unity engine?

Tags: unity, game-design, visual-studio-code

I'm a newbie and learning unity engine. I want to make a class diagram in unity to control my script efficiently. when I create a C# script look up the class diagram but I don't see that. my question is how do you create a class diagram in unity?

Comment: Do you mean something like a UML diagram?  If so you can try https://github.com/pierre3/PlantUmlClassDiagramGenerator or my docker wrapper https://github.com/minism/plantuml-csharp-docker

Comment: "I want to make a class diagram [...] to control my script efficiently" a class diagram is just a way of representing classes visually for analysis purposes. Are you interested in visual programming in Unity?